# Play 2.0 defining multiple templatesImport or routesImport in Build.scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've scoured all over the documentation and the internet to figure out how to add multiple values to the templatesImport or routesImport variables in Build.scala for Play 2.0.3. I can't seem to find anything on it nor figure out the correct scala syntax for this. I'm stuck at:

```
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
    templatesImport += "poc.model._"
    templatesImport += "views.tags._"
)
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On 2.1 snapshot but assume it's the same:

```
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
    templatesImport ++= Seq("poc.model._", "views.tags._")
)
```

For sub project builds, where you might have a base model PlayProject for common user, role, password reset, etc. CRUD operations, and another PlayProject for actual client's business model, a conflict naturally arises when trying:

```
templatesImport ++= Seq("com.foo.model", "com.bar.model")
```

so importing entire namespace `Seq("com.foo", "com.bar")` seems the only way around same named packages (short of renaming packages or typing out entire package name and not using `templatesImport` at all)

Answer (score 3):

I think you forgot a comma.

```
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
    templatesImport += "poc.model._", //new comma, no semicolon inference in parentheses like ()
    templatesImport += "views.tags._"
)
```

Comment: Your answer works as well. Marked virtualeyes' answer because I was actually looking to do what he suggested.